# How can I create an "aws.cloudformation" CloudWatch event type for a specific CloudFormation stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudtrail

I need to create an `aws.cloudformation` event type for a specific CloudFormation stack. For example when `StackA` receives the `UpdateStack` event, I need to be able to catch that event.

Through the console I was able to create the following event rule (which is an `AWS API Call via CloudTrail` type event):

```
{
    "source": [
        "aws.cloudformation"
    ],
    "detail-type": [
        "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
    ],
    "detail": {
        "eventSource": [
            "cloudformation.amazonaws.com"
        ],
        "eventName": [
            "UpdateStack",
            "CreateStack"
        ]
    }
}
```

However, this event isn't for any specific CloudFormation stack, and I don't see any option for adding anything specific (such as whenever `StackA` gets an `UpdateStack` call.

The [documentation for event types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/EventTypes.html) give examples of other event types and how we can add a specific resource that triggers the event. For example, with the `aws.codepipeline` event, you can specify a `pipeline` equal value to `PipelineA`, and then the event would get triggered whenever `PipelineA` gets to the state you specified in the `State` parameter.

How can I do something similar with an `aws.cloudformation` event type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the only way (as far as I have found) to get a stack-specific events is the notification configuration inside the stack, which can be only provided on creation/update.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-console-add-tags.html

Answer (score -1):

I'm looking similar solution and found that should work:
https://aws.amazon.com/ru/blogs/mt/tracking-aws-service-catalog-products-provisioned-by-individual-saml-users/

Step5
aws events put-rule --name "sc-add-user" --event-pattern "{"source":["aws.cloudformation"],"detail-type":["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],"detail":{"eventSource":["cloudformation.amazonaws.com"],"eventName":["CreateStack"]}}"